# When change orientation, the frame reactSetFrame:(CGRect)frame not changed

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a custom Native UI Component and I'm using `(void)reactSetFrame:(CGRect)frame` (method in `UIView+React.h`), when the orientation change, this method being called but with the old frame, the frame didn't change.

My usage:

```
- (void)reactSetFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    [super reactSetFrame:frame];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can make use of this :)

```
override func drawRect(rect : CGRect) {
        print(rect)
    }

override func traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        print("hi")
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Draw rect gets called when self.setNeedsDisplay is called and you can override `traitCollectionDidChange` capture it and force the view to layout itself :)

**EDIT**

Just realized you are using Objective-c

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGSize(rect.size));
}

-(void)traitCollectionDidChange:(UITraitCollection *)previousTraitCollection {
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but frame still not changed :/

Comment: @gran33 : You sure your view frame is changing ???? If your frame changes then only you will get the changed frame value in drawRect or you can modify it there manually :) Like if you have a view with autolayoutConstraint fixing it to four sides of viewCotroller you will see the drawRect gets called with updated frames always :) Am i missing something

Comment: Maybe `flex` doesn't support this?

Comment: @gran33 : Ohhhhh never worked with flex buddy :| no idea it surely works with normal UIView components though :) Tried it on my tableView CollectionView.

Comment: I work with `react-native` though, no just native app